# Bond Carry calculation

Tags: fixed-income, bond, bond-yields

I had a couple of questions about carry:

1. $-Carry for a bond: Coupon Income - Financing Costs, if I want to convert this to bps running, would I just divide by the fwd Dv01?
2. My understanding is, the above doesn't contain pull to par effects, therefore, it is more typical to use (YTM - Repo) as a measure of bond carry. This includes the pull to par effect.

I am using both metrics and there are substantial differences, especially at the short end - which leads me to think that this is p2p related differences.

Here's a simple example:
Bond Coupon 3.875%, maturity 30/04/2025 as of 17/08/2023 (Say t+1 settle). Quoted Price = 98.025. YTM is approx 5.10%.
Dirty Price is 99.19. Assuming a repo of 5.35% and fwd delivery of 17/10/2023, I get a fwd price of 98.27 => carry = -$0.25.

Fwd yield i get is 5.06%. So Fwd-Spot yield is -4bps of carry. If i compare this to $Carry/Fwd Dv01 I get -0.25/.01431 = -17bps? I am guessing my fwd Dv01 is wrong? I am calculating that is fwd Mod Dur x DirtyPrice x 1bp = 1.4426 x 1bp x 99.19.

Yield - Repo = -25bps, which for roughly 2 months is -4bps.

I am confused how to tie all of these numbers together.

Comment: anyone got any words of wisdom here?